# Operating system compatibility for SQL Anywhere 7

Tags: sql, windows-server-2008, sybase, sqlanywhere

Regarding which operating systems are compatible for Sybase SQL Anywhere 7

Currently i am using windows 2003 sever for Sybase SQL Anywhere 7 data base engine related operations and i wish to establish it under Server 2008 64Bit server environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Anywhere 7 is 16-year-old technology. There have been seven major versions released since v7. It has been end-of-lifed for at least six years, so it's not *supported* on any platform.

That said, I know of no reason it wouldn't work on newer versions of Windows.

But you really should find a way to upgrade to a later version. The latest version, 17, can't directly read v7 databases but it does have  the ability to convert v7 databases to a newer format.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Thanks Graeme, 
Are you know any export method from SQL Anywhere 7 to SQL Anywhere latest version. Because my SQL Anywhere 7 data base capacity is more than 8Gb. Anyway thanks for your support.

Comment: If you have SQL Anywhere 17 installed, you can do it in one step using the `dbunload` utility. Look up the [documentation](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/813e16456ce21014b96dc39365129dc6.html*loio813e16456ce21014b96dc39365129dc6) on the `-an` switch. You need to run something like: `dbunload -an new.db -c dbf=myold.db;uid=dba;pwd=sql"` You may need other switches but that should get you started.